# Use of \hiderowcolors & \showrowcolors within LyX

Tags: tables, color, lyx

Loading the [xcolor](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) package with the `[table]` option provides the command(s) `\rowcolors`(`*`) for alternate table row coloring. Any attempt, however, to use `\hiderowcolors` and `\showrowcolors` inside table rows within from LyX -- both in- and outisde a LyX table-float -- results in failing to compile a PDF. The error message is: `Undefined control sequence`.

It seems that there is no discussion/question upon this on either LyX-Users' [mailing list](http://www.lyx.org/MailingLists#toc2) or [tex.stackexchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com) itself. It certainly is preferable to resolve this in a clean way, i.e. with a correct usage of the above mentioned commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you simply haven't left any space between the ERT containing `\hiderowcolors`/`\showrowcolors`, so that TeX reads the letter(s) after the command as part of the command. E.g. if you put `\hiderowcolors` at the start of a table cell, and then write *text* right after the ERT, without spaces, TeX will see the command `\hiderowcolorstext`, which is undefined.

Solution: Put a pair of empty braces after `\hiderowcolors`, within the ERT. (You could also add a space after the ERT, but that will lead to wrong alignment.)

[image]

Comment: I (remember that I) did try that! Will re-try ASAP.

Comment: Grrr... it works! (...I *really* used a pair of empty braces... :-?)

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice though to be able to instruct `\rowcolors{no. of starting row}{no. of ending row}{1st color}{2nd color}`?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris You could always ask a new question about that (is it possible/how to do it).

Comment: I think this could be seen as an enhancement request to xcolor... So it'd better be directed to `xcolor` directly. This is why I did not already asked for that.