# How to apply alternate row coloring in a longtable in LyX?

Tags: color, lyx, longtable

In attempting to apply an alternate table row coloring (using `xcolor`) in a `longtable`, one confronts, sooner or later, problems in compiling a PDF.  In `xcolor`'s [documentation](http://www.ukern.de/tex/xcolor.html) it is clearly stated, under *Known Issues*, that **`\rowcolors[\hline]...` does not work with longtable**.

Within tex.SE, various solutions address the issue of alternate row coloring of *normal* tables, i.e. [How to create alternating rows in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5363/8272)  A nice way for auto-alternate row-coloring every table is posted at [Coloring every alternate table row](http://texblog.org/2011/09/02/coloring-every-alternate-table-row/) (see *Addendum* in the end of the post).

However, there is no direct question & answer referring to the combined use of `xcolor`'s `\rowcolors` command & `longtable`.  Moreover, searching the web for work-arounds, at least one solution, involves the use of [longtable and colortbl](http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/language/latex/latex25-SpecialEffectsShading/ar01s07.html).

Is there a way to use, within LyX, the `\rowcolors` (set of) command(s) provided by `xcolor` within `longtable`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adapting the solution given in the *Addendum* of the post [Coloring every alternate table row](http://texblog.org/2011/09/02/coloring-every-alternate-table-row/) worked just fine!  It was as simple as substituting `tabular` with `longtable`.

**A working example**

In `LyX`' *Preamble*, watch out for the `% alternate rowcolors for all long-tables` part of the code:

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

% define lightgray
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}

% alternate rowcolors for all tables
\let\oldtabular\tabular
\let\endoldtabular\endtabular
\renewenvironment{tabular}{\rowcolors{2}{white}{lightgray}\oldtabular}{\endoldtabular}

% alternate rowcolors for all long-tables
\let\oldlongtable\longtable
\let\endoldlongtable\endlongtable
\renewenvironment{longtable}{\rowcolors{2}{white}{lightgray}\oldlongtable} {
\endoldlongtable}

% Tables

% scale tables
\usepackage{graphicx}

% rulers for tabs
\usepackage{booktabs}
```

In the main body construct a longtable using LyX' own longtable capacity:

*Right click within a row of a table* > **More...** > **Settings** > **Longtable** (tab) > *Activate* **Use long table**.

**Example screenshots**

[image: An alt-rowcolored longtable with (reputation-aly ranked) tex.se user-names]

Avoiding (grey-)coloring of the longtable-footer, can be done by explicitly instructing `\rowcolor{white}` or using multiple `\cellcolor{white}` commands in the respective row (well, the first one of the table).

[image: An alt-rowcolored longtable with (reputation-aly ranked) tex.se user-names, white footers]

Comment: Also, both the `\show`- and `\hiderowcolors` commands work perfectly as showed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61127/8272