# Automatically insert capital letters as alphabetical breakpoints in a sorted column of names

Tags: tables, sorting, alphabet

Recently I used [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) to prepare a list with 200+ guest names for a wedding (page 1 illustrated below). Actually, it was a table including invited family names, the number of persons of each invited family, the number of the table given to the family and an alternative table number.

[image: Table of families invited in a wedding, alphabetically sorted (1st column)]

The table was initially created in a spreadsheet and afterwards extracted as a `csv` file which was the basis for the final "guest list". The family names (1st column of the table) were already alphabetically sorted. Small caps were applied for family names, [alternate table row-coloring (for a longtable within LyX)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61747/8272), bold numbers referring to the tables and other font details.

In addition, I manually inserted capital letters, just before family names started with a "new" letter, to give the sense of alphabetically grouped names  and ease tracing them when the moments come were 50~100 people altogether, waiting in the entrance of the event hall, expect to be guided to their table.

**The question:** is there a way to automatically insert single rows with capital letters as "breakpoints" (as shown in the attached page above) using a "normal", sorted, column of names?  And how about automatically adding some custom command in each of the "letter"-rows, like for example `\hiderowcolors{}` and `\showrowcolors{}` in each following row? I imagine that something like this could be useful to create easier to read long "guests lists".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably easier to get the spreadsheet to add the headings as it writes the csv file but anyway If you want Tex to do it, then something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\let\savedcr\LT@tabularcr
\def\LT@tabularcr{\xxLT@tabularcr\savedcr}

\let\savedendhead\endhead
\def\endhead{\xxLT@tabularcr\savedendhead}

\def\xxLT@tabularcr#1#2{%
\ifcat a\noexpand#2%
\if\thisletter#2%
\expandafter\@gobble
\else
\expandafter\@firstofone
\fi
{\expandafter#1\expandafter\letterrow\expandafter#2\expandafter}%
\fi
\savedcr#2}

\def\letterrow#1{%
\noalign{\gdef\thisletter{#1}}%
\rowcolor{blue}%
\multicolumn{\LT@cols}{c}{%
\color{white}%
\global\advance\rownum\m@ne
\bfseries\thisletter}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{1}{gray!20}{white}
\def\thisletter{?}
\def\zzz#1{\def\a{#1}\show\a#1}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
\rowcolor{yellow}Name&Number\\
\hline
\endhead
Apple & 2\\
Artichoke &3\\
Banana&1\\
Cabbage&6\\
Cucumber&8
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```