# Colorizing lines in a longtable, but not the caption

Tags: color, longtable

I'm trying to colorize lines in a longtable, which is working except it is colorizing also the caption, like this -

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[table,hyperref,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\rowcolors{2}{green!25}{} 
\begin{longtable}{| p{.3\textwidth}| p{.7\textwidth}|}
\hline
cell one & cell two \\ \hline
cell three & cell four \\ \hline
cell five & cell six \\ \hline
cell seven & cell eight \\
\hline
\caption{Just a test table}
\end{longtable}
```

This always colorizes the caption line if there is an odd number of lines. This is in emacs 24.5.50.1, and utilising auctex in debian 8.

How can I get it so that the caption is always uncolored please?

Comment: See the second part of the answer to this question. It fixes your problem (duplicate): [How to apply alternate row coloring in a longtable in LyX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61747/4778)

Comment: In other words, you should add the cell colour definition in the caption, like `\caption{\cellcolor{white} Just a test table}`.

Comment: I'd looked at the reference quoted before but totally missed the `\cellcolor{white}` part, and that does solve the problem, although it does need several passes or builds.  Thanks.

Comment: Several passes? Weird, I don't know why that is the case. It took me one. But glad it helped! :D