# Table: Alternating rowcolours / banding

Tags: tables, color

I have a table with over 400 entries. I wanted to make it more readable by colouring the cells in grey and white. I know how to do it with a regular table. But I cannot get it to work with a longtable environment. Thanks!

Below: A two page MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{7cm}
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.8cm}
}

 %header
 \rowcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}
 \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{\textbf{ID}} & 
 \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{\textbf{Journal}} & 
 \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{\textbf{Article}} & 
 \textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{\textbf{Year}} \\
%content
1     & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
2     & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
3     & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
4     & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
5     & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
6     & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
7     & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
8     & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
9     & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
10    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
11    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
12    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
13    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
14    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
15    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
16    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
17    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
18    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
19    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
20    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
21    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
22    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
23    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
24    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
25    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
26    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
27    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
28    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
29    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
30    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
31    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
32    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
33    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
34    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
\midrule
35    & arxiv & Platzhalter & 2019 \\
        \bottomrule
 \end{longtable}
  \label{tab:addlabel}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61748/121799) work for you?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue has been solved by a comment.